# Append dataframe with column names alone to another dataframe with data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes as below.

**Dataframe 1 (with only column names and no data):**

```
Name   Age   Gender
```

0 rows * 3 columns

**Dataframe 2 (has data with over 1000 rows):**

```
level_1   level_2    level_3
AAA       26         M
BBB       19         F
CCC       24         F
```

1000 rows * 3 columns

I have to append both the above dataframes.

**Expected Output**

**Dataframe 1**

```
Name   Age   Gender
AAA    26    M
BBB    19    F
CCC    24    F
```

**What i tried so far:**

```
dataframe_1 = dataframe_1.append(dataframe_2,ignore_index = True)
```

**which gave me the below output:**

```
Name   Age   Gender   level_1   level_2   level_3
NaN    NaN   NaN      AAA       26        M
NaN    NaN   NaN      BBB       19        F
NaN    NaN   NaN      CCC       24        F
```

1000 rows * 6 columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Need same columns names for correct alignment of columns between both DataFrames, so set columns names by from another DataFrame:

```
dataframe_2.columns = dataframe_1.columns
dataframe_1 = dataframe_1.append(dataframe_2,ignore_index = True)
```

Another solution:

```
dataframe_1 = pd.concat([dataframe_1, dataframe_2],ignore_index = True)
```

---

```
print (dataframe_1)
  Name Age Gender
0  AAA  26      M
1  BBB  19      F
2  CCC  24      F
```

Comment: Terrific.. Thank you.. Works as expected :) Thank you everyone for quick response

Comment: @shankarBalu - one minutes difference between answers. :)

Comment: Yeah. 3 answers in 3 minutes.. :)

Answer (score 4):

Given what you're hoping for, I don't see any problem with:

```
dataframe_2.columns = dataframe_1.columns
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `.columns` attribute for the first dataframe with the second's:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'val': ['Cat', 'Tiger', 'Ball', 'Bat'],
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 1]
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'waka': [],
    'wattafak': []
})
df.columns = df2.columns
df
```

```
    waka    wattafak
0   1   Cat
1   2   Tiger
2   3   Ball
3   1   Bat
```